# Remove a portion of a variable length string and store it in a new variable

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I'm trying to remove the HH MM(minute) SS section in the following example:

```
data=`security find-certificate -c "ABC Company Root 2016 CA" -p | openssl x509 -text | grep "Not After"`

echo $data
Not After : Mar 6 01:00:53 2026 GMT
date1=`cut -c 13-32 <<< $data`
echo $date1
Mar 6 01:00:53 2026
```

The problem is that I cannot go by character position because the text length can change. Example, the date could be 16th instead of 6 (or any double digit). The date will be derived and will not be static. Therefore I need a way to look for characters immediately before and after the ":" and remove them.

I would like the output to be in the following format (MM DD YYYY):

Mar 6 2026

Comment: I don't understand ... `Mar 6 2026` is not in a format of `MM:DD:YY` ... ????

Comment: Sorry I didn't add more code. It has been updated. Please remove my strike if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bash`:

```
data='Not After : Mar 6 01:00:53 2026 GMT'
read x x x m d x y x <<< $data
echo "$m $d $y"
```

Output:

```
Mar 6 2026
```

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution than string parsing is to use `date -d` to read the date in and then `+<format>` to spit it back out in the format of your choice. `%b %-e %Y` will give you `Mar 6 2026`, and you have the ability to change it to another format if you like. See `date --help` for a list of format specifiers.

```
$ date -d "$date1" +'%b %-e %Y'
Mar 6 2026
```